# When to use defer_lock on std::shared_lock?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, share, deferred

I see from cppreference:

```
std::shared_lock<Mutex>::shared_lock
 C++ Thread support library std::shared_lock 
shared_lock() noexcept;
(1) (since C++14)
shared_lock( shared_lock&& other ) noexcept;
(2) (since C++14)
explicit shared_lock( mutex_type& m );
(3) (since C++14)
shared_lock( mutex_type& m, std::defer_lock_t t ) noexcept;
(4) (since C++14)
```

And:

```
4) Does not lock the associated mutex.
```

Well, if this defer_lock means we don't lock the mutex, then what's the usage of this `lock` at all?

When do we need to specify `defer_lock` parameter, for what kind of usage scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can always lock the mutex later, using `lock()`.

Sometimes, due to scoping rules, or whatever, you don't want to immediately lock anything when the lock object is created; but you still want to have the lock released, automatically, upon leaving the declaration's scope.

This allows you to instantiate a lock object, and not lock anything right away, but `lock()` it later.